# Github default account is not working after changing for multiple accounts

Tags: github, ssh-keys, ed25519, multiple-accounts

I have used my office github account. But i was need to add my personal github account also. My office github account is `dinukafrost`. My personal github account is `dinuka`.

I did following steps.

1. Create ssh keys. (I have already had ssh key for office account)
2. Add public keys to github. (My office public key was added)
3. Create ~/.ssh/config file.

My ssh keys.

```
id_ed25519_dinuka  
id_ed25519_dinukafrost  
id_ed25519_dinukafrost.pub  
id_ed25519_dinuka.pub
```

My config file

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa

# dinukafrost

Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_dinukafrost

# dinuka

Host dinuka github.com
 HostName github.com
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_dinuka
```

These command are given correct response.

```
➜  ssh -T git@github.com
Hi dinuka! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
➜  ssh -T git@dinuka    
Hi dinuka! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Now i can use my personal account with `dinuka` host. eg - `origin  git@dinuka:dinuka/laravel_test.gi`

But i can't use my office repos that i was using. eg - `origin  git@github.com:MyCompany/lp-service-registry.git`

It is throwing following error

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can i fix this issue. Is any way to find any logs for fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ssh -T git@github.com
> Hi dinuka!
> ```

That means a `github.com` entry authenticates you with your personal account.
Probably because of the entry `Host dinuka github.com`, instead of `Host dinuka`

I prefer using entries with a specific name rather than "github.com".
(And I always include `User git`, to avoid the `git@` part of the SSH URL).

```yaml
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa

# dinukafrost

Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_dinukafrost

# dinuka

Host dinuka
 HostName github.com
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_dinuka
 User git
```

Check if `ssh -Tv github.com` does authenticate you as `dinukafrost`.
If not, replace `Host github.com` with `Host dinukafrost`, and repeat the test with `ssh -Tv dinukafrost`.